maven-pdf-plugin change the layout of front page
I have a simple configuration for maven pdf plugin
document xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/DOCUMENT/1.0.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/DOCUMENT/1.0.1 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/document-1.0.1.xsd"
          outputName="${project.name}">

    <meta>
        <title>${project.name} User Guide</title>
        <author>Acme Inc.</author>
    </meta>

    <toc name="Table of Contents">
        <item name="Introduction" ref="index.md"/>
        <item name="Other" ref="other.md"/>
    </toc>

    <cover>
        <coverTitle>${project.name}</coverTitle>
        <coverSubTitle>version ${project.version}</coverSubTitle>
        <coverType>User Guide</coverType>
        <projectName>${project.name}</projectName>
        <projectLogo>project.logo</projectLogo>
        <companyName>Acme Inc.</companyName>
        <companyLogo>Acme.logo</companyLogo>
    </cover>
</document>

it generates a pdf, but the front page seems to be hard coded without any option to override the default layout. any thought?
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pdf-plugin/usage.html is very limited, there is a section about Document Descriptor but it point to non-existing doxia page https://maven.apache.org/doxia/doxia/doxia-core/document.html ...
